# Trying to convert a c++ ostream to a python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, c++, pandas, boost, boost-python

I have made a c++ application which retrieves a large amount of static data as a ostream. I have then used Boost.python to access this application and run it from python. I am able to run the application from python which prints to the CLI all the static data. However, I need to input this into a pandas dataframe.

I have attempted to convert the ostream to a stringstream but this doesnt work without having to change large amounts of code, so ideally it would be easier to convert the ostream into a string, and then send the string to python. Or retrieve the ostream in python and convert it to a string there and then.

I have attempted to do this as so: 
`boost::python::scope().attr("pyString") = pyString;`

But i cannot seem to retrieve pyString on the python side.

If anyone has any insight on how I can get the stream in a string or any format which I can load into a dataframe in python, you would be a life saver

I'm open to explore many avenues, as this being completed is essential. Thank you.

I'm using python 3.7 and the latest boost. Happy to provide any more information needed.

Comment: What do you mean by *storing* data in an `ostream`? An `ostream` is a device for outputting data somewhere else, whether it be a terminal, a file, a string, etc. It's not really an abstraction for storage per se.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense for what I'm seeing. Sorry, I'm not proficient with c++; Do you know how I can save the output of the ostream to a variable to then send to python?

Comment: A cheap alternative is to simply write your data to a csv file and read that in using `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: To answer your question, one would need to see the code that shows *how* you are retrieving static data from an `ostream`. Also, beware of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).